# Unable to log iptables

Tags: iptables, logging, log-files, syslog

I'm having trouble getting iptables to log to any file.

My iptables looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1366 packets, 433582 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 869    60656 LOG        icmp --  venet0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 7
```

Syslogd is the only log helper running.  The default syslog.conf didn't work, so I tried adding  "kern.=debug   -/var/log/iptables.log".  But the file already has "kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log".

There are recent syslog entries, so it's not a permissions thing.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.1 with 2.6.32-042stab061.2

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling syslog fixed the problem.

I forgot one of the golden rules of computing.  If all else fails, restart, if that fails, reinstall.